# Why does RetroArch make my SNES games look so low-resolution?

Tags: snes, retroarch

In Retroarch, I am using the glcore driver and the BSNES-HD-BETA Core with the default settings. I've tried making many changes to aspect ratio, custom scaling, custom screen resolution, shaders, etc. with no luck.

My games look pixelated and when I watch others play online, their games look higher resolution. See screenshots.

**What settings can I use to make my games look as good as youtube examples of snes games?**  My screen is on the left. Notice the pixelated edges.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The image on the left is how the game looks by default.  The image on the right has a shader applied.  This is not necessarily a "higher resolution" - in this case, it looks like a simple blur has been applied to reduce pixelation.

### Shader examples

No shader:
[image: No shader]

2xbrz-linear:
[image: 2xbrz-linear]

crt/crt-royale-ntsc-320px-composite:
[image: crt/crt-royale-ntsc-320px-composite]

---

Retroarch has a *ton* of shaders. You can find more examples and documentation [here](https://www.retroarch.com/?page=shaders).  Try out a bunch of them and see which ones you like best.